# How track a link embeded in facebook page?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter, google-analytics

I want to track newsletter tab from my facebook page.
I put this code in the source code of my site:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>

 </head>
 <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
           var fb_param = {};
           fb_param.pixel_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
           fb_param.value = '0.00';
           (function(){
             var fpw = document.createElement('script');
             fpw.async = true;
             fpw.src = (location.protocol=='http:'?'http':'https')+'://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
             var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
           })();
   </script>

   <noscript>
        <img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=xxxxxxxxx&amp;value=0" />
   </noscript>


 </body>
```

Is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Google will automatically track referrals as long as you have the Google code in your source. If you can modify the embedded link in your Facebook page, you might want to look at adding _utm variables to the urls. Google will automatically recognize this from the url and add it with those parameter within your GA account. To build or get more information on _utm variables go here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863

I would set utm_source to facebook, and utm_medium to newsletter-tab:

```
http://www.example.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=newsletter-tab
```